# How to modify date in flask from JSON format

Tags: json, date, templates, flask

I'm passing date directly from JSON to a template, but I cannot modify how it should be displayed. I'd like to display DD.MM.YYYY but it displays directly from JSON format (2020-08-05T00:00:00) I've tried using a custom filter but it gives a bunch of errors.

**Edit**
*JSON*

```
"startDate": "2020-07-07T00:00:00"
```

*app.py*

```
@app.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
def generate_pdf():
    return render_to_pdf(request.json)

def render_to_pdf(context_dict):
    templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./templates/")
    templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
    TEMPLATE_FILE = "pdf_template.html"
    template = templateEnv.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ json.Date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}
```

Comment: can you be more precise {{ startDate }} gives 2020-08-05T00:00:00

Comment: just use {{ startDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}

Comment: It gives an error ```jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'strftime'```

Comment: It works but in your case i guess you are missing some modules. Lets try a different approach can you use your own filter?

Comment: this means you already converted your date object into a string. you need to strptime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', startDate).strftime('%d.%m.%Y'). You should have been more specific how you create your json. You should do this conversion before inserting the date into the json as a string. Please provide more code

Comment: i agree with @c8999c3f964f64, whether your json has date in string format or what?

Comment: I've changed object from str to datetime and now it's working, but it's strange cause it is directly from json so ...Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

strftime converts a date object into a string by specifying a format you want to use

you can do

```
now = datetime.now() # <- datetime object
now_string = now.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

however, if you already converted your datetime object into a string (or getting strings from an api or something), you can convert the string back to a datetime object using strptime

```
date_string = '2020-08-05T00:00:00'
date_obj = strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')  # <- the format the string is currently in
```

You can first to strptime and then strftime directly from that to effectively convert a string into a different string, but you should avoid this if possible

```
converted_string = strptime(original_string, 'old_format').strftime('new_format')
```

This topic may be confusing because when you print(now) (remember, the datetime object), python automatically "represents" this and converts it into a string. however, it isnt actually a string at this time, but rather a datetime object. python can't print that, so it converts it - but you wont be able to jsonify this directly, for example.